# Different values in different instances of the same usercontrol in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am working on creating a map for an application, which I need to present in two different ways. One mini-map and one regular map, they are both made up of one single `UserControl`. My issue is that I am trying to find a smooth way of displaying the regular-sized map with area names, and the mini-map without. I have been looking into `DependencyProperties` as a possible way of doing this, or at least a way to illustrate my train of thought. What I have so far is this.

```
    public bool MiniMap
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(MiniMapProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MiniMapProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty MiniMapProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MiniMap", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(myMap), 
        new PropertyMetadata());
```

I then have all the TextBlocks with the right labels in the UserControl, and are currently trying to remove the Text property if the MiniMap property is set as true, and let them be if it is false. Currently I am just doing it on the title of the map, but I can loop through them all once I get this one to work.

```
    if (MiniMap == true)
        {
            this.Title.Text = "";
        }
```

I am then instantiating this UserControl in a different View twice, with the MiniMap property set as true in one case, and false in the other.

```
    <map:myMap x:Name="myMap" Visibility="Collapsed" MiniMap="False"/>
    <map:myMap x:Name="miniMap" Visibility="Visible" MiniMap="True"/>
```

The idea here is that once you click the Map button, the big map comes up (changes `Visibility` to `Visible`) and since the MiniMap property is set to false in this instance, then TextBlock(s) should be empty, or removed preferably - but that is a different issue. My problem here tho is that no matter what I do both instances of my `UserControl` always seems to have the same value for the `MiniMap` property, so I can only turn the TextBlock either on in both cases, or off in both. Anyone have any idea how I can get this to work, or have another solution better suited for my problem?

Comment: Are yoiu declaring 2 instance of this usercontrol, or is a single usercontrol that handle within the instance both the maps?

Comment: See my edit on the last code snippet. I am instantiating the same UserControl twice, yet one is scaled down a bit (mini map). I just need them to figure out if they are the mini map- or the regular version.

Comment: I don't know if it's your question formatting, but both your User Controls have the same name. This looks like an issue if you are referencing them by name.

Comment: I guess this is not your real code, cause you gave the same name to both of your control.

Comment: That was just me being lazy copypasting the line above sorry. They have different names in my application. Sorry. I have removed parts from the code (scaling, margins and sizing etc) to keep it cleaner.

Comment: Are these control created from the start of your application, or you instantiate them using a command or a click event?

Comment: From the start, they are always there - just not always visible.

Comment: So if you make a dummy event in code behind and check these controls in debug ,they have MiniMap property set at the same value?

Comment: I will check, so far I only know because if I put the Text in the `if (MiniMap == True)` to something like "ASDFASDF" it will show up in both instances, if I change it to false both will be the default text.

Comment: I think a simpler route to take would be to have two separate User Controls sharing the same ViewModel. From a performance and efficiency standpoint it would be effectively the same.

Comment: I've been testing it out now, it seems they will always be false. Even if I put both instances to true, they still come out as false. So the problem probably is with my instantiation. `<map:myMap MiniMap="True">` does not set it to true. I guess my problem would be solved by solving this tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a propertychanged callback

```
public static DependencyProperty MiniMapProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MiniMap", 
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(myMap), 
    new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMiniMapPropertyChanged)));


private static void OnMiniMapPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = sender as myMap;
            if (control != null && (bool)e.NewValue == true)
                control.Title.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: Now I get an error "The name 'True' does not exist in the current context". Seems it doesn't recognize it as a boolean.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Put a brakpoint inside the event and check if it's called again after you create your controls. If yes, then you a probably changin the MiniMap value somewhere and you forgot it

Comment: Well I'll be damned, that did the trick! I'm not quite sure how though, I'd love a quick explanation as to why this worked if you have time. In any case, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tom You have not given a dafult value for your dependecy property, so the system take the default value for the MiniMap property that is false for a bool (that's why you see false for both your instance). Since you didn't register an event for the property changed, i suppose that the application simply ignore your changes to the property when you set it in the xaml

Comment: Aha. I followed some other instructional video that told me that I had to remove the default value in order to set it. Still trying to get the hang of the variations of PropertyChanged methods, so it's good to learn. Thanks for both solving my problem and explaining what I did wrong. May you have the best of weekends! :)